# What does ^L in (Emacs Lisp) source code mean?

Tags: emacs, elisp, special-characters

Several times I see `^L` in (mostly Emacs Lisp) source codes that looks like are separators of larger logical groups. Is it their real purpose? And if so, how can I use them? Is there a built-in Emacs functionality that utilize it?

Comment: None of the answers have mentioned that `^L` is just the default value. You can set a buffer-local `page-delimiter` regexp to anything you want, to get page navigation functionality using some custom value.

Comment: This is the [form feed character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed), often represented as `\x0c` or `\f`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a [page break](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PageBreaks).

> [...]
>
> A page break can also be used for a logical separation of source-code
>   sections. Emacs has commands and key bindings that use page breaks, such
>   as ‘forward-page’ (`C-x ]` or `C-]`), ‘backward-page’
>   (`C-x [` or `C-[`), and 'narrow-to-page' (`C-x n p`). Other functions, such as
>   ‘mark-page’, operate on the content of a page. See also PageMode.

Comment: Otherwise known as a FORM-FEED character to people who remember line printers.

Comment: Btw, they are in RFCs too (in .txts), but firefox doesn't show them.

Answer (score 41):

The Emacs commands `backward-page` and `forward-page` (`C-x [` and `C-x ]`), among others, take advantage of `^L`s placed in the code as separators.

The habit did not propagate much to languages other than Emacs-lisp, but most languages treat `^L` as a blank, so you can use these separators in your favorite language if you like the idea. You can type your own `^L`s with `C-q C-l`.

Answer (score 7):

When exploring a big file with multiple of such "pages" the function "narrow-to-page" (<kbd>C-x n p</kbd>) is handy: it hides everything not in the current page. Then for example searching for a function name to see the callers only leads to matches in that section, so you can really focus on understanding the narrowed region.

Use widen (<kbd>C-x n w</kbd>) to see the whole file again.

Answer (score 6):

See also [Pretty Control-L](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettyControlL) if you want to change how Control-l characters appear -- e.g., use a highlighted line instead of just `^L`.

Answer (score 3):

That is indeed a page break character, which on older line printers skipped to the next page or paper.  Code-wise, it does nothing; it is only there to split the code into larger sections.  There are convenient Emacs commands to jump to the next and previous "page", and inserting these characters takes advantage of that.